# How to make GCC or Clang compile all the code, even unreachable?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang++

If I compile the following code:

```
void f() {
int* ptr = 0;
try {
    *ptr = 9;
} catch (...) {
    printf("caught");
}
```

Gcc doesn`t compile code that it considers unreachable, so the resulting assembly does not contain the catch block. How do I make GCC compile everything?

I need this because I am researching the possibility of passing C++ exceptions from the kernel to user programs, so if the code above is executed, the kernel will throw an exception after *ptr=9 that should be caught in the catch block.

Comment: `catch (...)` does not catch seg-faults (bad addresses).

Comment: You might be able to catch SIGSEGV though. But handling it is tricky.

Comment: @RichardCritten, as I tried to write in the question, the modified OS I am running the code throws an Exception which can be caught, rather than a signal.

Comment: Then sounds like you need a modified compiler supporting your OS.

Comment: @ДмитрийВоронецкий gcc out of the box can remove the catch since it knows that assigning a value to a dereferenced pointer can't throw an exception. You need to modify the compiler to make it aware of your OS features.

Comment: You are dereferencing a null pointer which is Undefined Behavior in C++. You can't expect anything definite from GCC with that code.

Comment: @ks1322, GCC would still omit the catch block if I was dereferencing a non-null pointer, but one that would still cause a page fault.

Comment: This is not a C question. Please remove the C tag

Comment: The compiler (optimizer usually) is allowed to omit the entire section code if it can prove it contains Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @RichardCritten Not exactly the way it works, it is more like - the compiler may assume that no construct is causing an undefined behavior in the code, and perform the optimizations accordingly. In the code above, it may assume `ptr` is a valid pointer always.

Comment: IMHO, the try block is removed because of semantic analysis (exactly static analysis) component inside compilers. You may re-compile compilers with semantic analysis component disabled. Semantic analysis ensures you get code with higher quality.

Comment: @LayneLiu It really won't help. The compiler is supposed to generate some code path that is actually leading into this block. But in this case there is no such a path.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Does it mean the compiler is buggy in this case? Because it seems that it assumes *ptr =9 raises no exception.

Comment: @LayneLiu Why, is it wrong in this assumption?

Comment: @EugeneSh. As Kevin said, "gcc out of the box can remove the catch since it knows that assigning a value to a dereferenced pointer can't throw an exception".  But in this case it can throw an exception. In static analysis terminology, it's unsound. semantics analysis should be sound, right?

Comment: @LayneLiu: The compiler's choice to remove the `catch` is sound.  Either `*ptr` refers to a valid `int` (or transparently compatible such as `unsigned int`) object, in which case the language rules provide that the assignment succeeds without any exception, or else `*ptr` doesn't refer to a valid `int`-compatible object, in which case the language rules provide that you are in the realm of "undefined behavior", in which case there are no guarantees at all, not even the ones that handle exceptions.

Comment: In particular, the language does not say "in case the result of the indirection is not a valid object, the compiler shall generate a memory access which can be intercepted by the kernel and translated into a C++ exception".   You get a little bit closer with `volatile int*` ....

Comment: Another note: `int* ptr = 0;` has nothing to do with the address `0x0000'0000`.  A literal zero is recognized as a "null pointer constant" and acts like a null pointer, which could be some special non-zero value.  It's a bit difficult to portably get a pointer to point at address zero, something like `memset` will usually work.

Comment: @LayneLiu The OP's case requires *defining* the (currently undefined) behavior of dereferencing an invalid pointer as throwing an exception whatsoever, and then implement a compiler which would provide such a behavior.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Almost but not quite.  OP seems to want it defined as producing a memory access instruction that will result in a hardware fault and vectoring execution to kernel-provided fault handlers.  But without the `volatile` keyword in play, `*ptr = 9;` doesn't even try to be a memory access, just an expression evaluation.

Comment: Add `volatile bool t = false; if (t) throw 0;` so it has to assume something throws. And then you can work on making the kernel throw exceptions to user space. If you have that working you can start modifying the compiler to assume any expression can throw and remove the volatile hack. My money is on that you never get that far.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of accomplishing this without creating a new compiler backend would be to wrap the standard types with classes (e.g., `int` becomes `Int`). These class replacements for the standard types would use operator overloading that could be recognized as possibly throwing an exception.

This would be a hack, of course. But, I have seen this technique used by an automatic differentiation generator.

However, if the compiler can determine *a priori* that the code would generate undefined behavior, then there is not much you can do about what it decides to do with that knowledge. It can just decide the whole block of code would never execute, and skip generating any code at all.

Comment: This does work, thank you, but not with optimisations.

Comment: @ДмитрийВоронецкий Even if you made implementation of the overloads not to be inlined, the LTO might still do some DCE. You have to somehow add the possibility the overloaded operation might throw an exception. Something like `volatile bool gotta_throw = false;` ... `if (gotta_throw) throw BAD;`

Answer (score 0):

Your specific example is partly covered by `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks`. With this option, Clang treats null pointer dereferences as externally observable behavior, and does not elide them. However, it seems this option does not play well with `-fnon-call-exceptions` (at least in Clang 11), which is expect to emit exception handling tables for code that can trap. GCC handles this as expected and generates code for the `catch` handler.